# How to run a compiled binary which writes to /dev/evdev/event* without rooting the device?

Tags: root-access

I want to try [this record and replay tool](http://www.androidreran.com/software.php), but do not want to root my device.

Is it possible to run a binary which might need root access, without rooting the device?

Comment: Am I missing something? It seems like you're asking "Can I get root access without getting root access?" or something. In which case, the answer is *no*, you can't get root without getting root. Doing pretty much anything outside of `ls` in `/dev/` requires root privelages.

Comment: I understand, also the down voting on the question is not without reason. The reason I am asking this question, is because I am not sure if writing to /dev/evdev/evnt* really needs root access. Also there are no updates on the RERAN project since last two years, hence I thought, things might have changed. Thanks for the inputs though.

Comment: RERAN is actually writing to /dev/input/event* and not /dev/evdev/event*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching and trial and error, I could run replay.exe from RERAN, without rooting my device.

For some reason I could not copy and exectute replay.exe to/from /data/local as the original article suggests, but I could do it to/from /data/local/tmp.

I tested it on 3 devices. HTC-One mobile, Google Nexus 7 tab, Samsung Galaxy tab 10.

Here are details.

- I had to enable developer option and enable USB debugging
- Install USB driver for Android on my Windows 7
- Once I see the device in adb run following commands

  - .\adb.exe push replay.exe /data/local/tmp/ to copy the binary
  - .\adb.exe shell /data/local/tmp/replay.exe to run the binary

Now one thing I cannot understand but why does it run when copied to /data/local/tmp?

- Is it a security hole or debugging aid?
- Or writing to /dev/input/event* really do not need root access?